# Compile error: invalid qualifier when looping through worksheets

Tags: excel, loops, compiler-errors, vba

I am trying to copy cells from several worksheets to a summary worksheet if their date (held in col. G) falls within a given range.  I want the macro to loop through column g in each sheet and pull in the information where there is a match before moving on to the next worksheet to do the same.  Currently my code presents a  compile error: Invalid qualifier for the x value within rng...I an new to VBA and can't see what I have done wrong.

```
Sub Copy_ProjectSummaryData()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws_num As Integer
Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Dim shtDest As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As Date
Set starting_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'remember which worksheet is 
active in the beginning
ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Set shtDest = Sheets("Summary")

destRow = 4 'start copying to this row
destRow2 = 4 'start copying to this row
destRow3 = 4 'start copying to this row
destRow4 = 4 'start copying to this row
startdate = CDate(InputBox("Begining Date"))
enddate = CDate(InputBox("End Date"))

'Clear contents from sheet before running new report
Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

'Find and pull in Escalated Risks within the date range for the report
For i = 1 To ws_num
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
        Set rng = 
Application.Intersect(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("G16:G20"), 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).UsedRange)
    For Each c In rng.Cells
         If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
        'Starting 6 cells to the left of c (col A),
        '  copy an 8-cell wide block to the other sheet,
        '  pasting it in Col B on row destRow
        c.Offset(0, -6).Resize(1, 8).Copy _
        shtDest.Cells(destRow, 2)
        destRow = destRow + 1
      End If
      Next
Next

'Find and paste Risk Project Name
For i = 1 To ws_num

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate

Set rng = Application.Intersect(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("G16:G20"), 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).UsedRange)
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
    '  copy C3 to the other sheet,
    '  pasting it in Col A on row destRow
    Range("C3").Copy _
    shtDest.Cells(destRow2, 1)
    destRow2 = destRow2 + 1
    End If
Next
Next

'Find and pull in New Issues within the date range for the report
For i = 1 To ws_num
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate

    Set rng = 
Application.Intersect(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("G22:G26"), 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).UsedRange)
    For Each c In rng.Cells
         If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
        'Starting 6 cells to the left of c (col A),
        '  copy an 8-cell wide block to the other sheet,
        '  pasting it in Col B on row destRow
        c.Offset(0, -6).Resize(1, 8).Copy _
        shtDest.Cells(destRow3, 11)
        destRow3 = destRow3 + 1
      End If
      Next
 Next
'Find and paste Issues Project Name
For i = 1 To ws_num

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
    Set rng = 
Application.Intersect(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("G22:G26"), 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).UsedRange)
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
    '  copy C3 to the other sheet,
    '  pasting it in Col A on row destRow
    Range("C3").Copy _
    shtDest.Cells(destRow4, 10)
    destRow4 = destRow4 + 1
    End If
Next
Next

starting_ws.Activate 'activate the worksheet that was originally active

Range("B4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("K4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("J4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `X` as a `Long`. A `Long` does not have ranges. You should be using `Sheets(X)` rather than just `X`:

```
Set rng = Application.Intersect(Sheets(x).Range("G:G"), Sheets(x).UsedRange)
```

Comment: Thank you Rory,  however if I change the Long to Range or Worksheet it creates a type mismatch with     For x = A To Z    and if I add sheets(x) in here it creates a compile error:variable required -cant assign to this expression (?).  i have changed the x to sheets(x) in rng.  Still not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks,  I did change that but then I have an error .  in the the line stating X=A to Z the x is highlighted as a run time error 9:subscript out of range.  I presumed this was because it was still set as long but this is where I am still lost.

Comment: That error can't occur there. Is X still declared as Long? (It should be)

Comment: sorry,,,,I've replaced the code above with the edits I made

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I now have this working using a loop.  Its clunky and not the fasted but its working.  I edited my code above to show what I did.  Feedback on obvious things I could do better would be welcomed :)

Comment: I think it would be a lot faster to use an autofilter and copy the columns you want. Recording a macro should get you 90% of the code for that.

Comment: At the very least, adding `Application.Screenupdating = False` to the start should speed things up a bit.